# Vuejs + Axios Отправить файлы на сервер

Tags: post, vue.js, axios

Есть стандартная структура проекта vue-cli с template

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <h2>Загрузка архивов </h2>
    <ul>
      <li>

        <form id="uploadForm" action='upload_file' role="form" method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data>

          <input type="file" id="file" name="file">

          <input type=submit value=Upload>

        </form>


      </li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Формирование отчета</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>С <input type="date"></li>
      <li>По <input type="date"></li>
      <li><input type="submit" value="Сформировать"/></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'hello',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Взаиморасчеты v0.1 Beta'
    }
  },
  method: {
    uploadFile: function (event) {
      const file = event.target.files[0]
      axios.post('192.168.1.222:8080/upload', file, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Не могу понять, как отправить выбранные файлы на сервер (не один файл)

Как отправить запрос вроде разобрался

```
  methods: {
    uploadFiles () {
      const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }
      axios.post('http://192.168.1.222:8080/upload', document.getElementById('file').files[0], config)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error.response)
        })
    }
  }
}
```

Но сервер выдает ответ:
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)**

Разобрался как "забрать" файлы из input'тов.
С текстовыми полями все ок., а вот сами файлы не отправляются

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'hello',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    uploadFiles () {
      var s = this
      const data = new FormData(document.getElementById('uploadForm'))
      var imagefile = document.querySelector('#file')
      console.log(imagefile.files[0])
      data.append('file', imagefile.files[0])
      data.append('name', s.name)
      data.append('email', s.email)
      axios.post('http://192.168.1.222:8080/upload', data, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error.response)
        })
    }
  }
}
```

Вывод консоли.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так корректно отправляется

```
   <form id="uploadForm" name="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple><br>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email">


      <input type=button value=Upload @click="this.uploadFiles">

    </form>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
      name: 'hello',
      data () {
        return {
          msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
        }
      },
      methods: {
        uploadFiles () {
          var s = this
          const data = new FormData(document.getElementById('uploadForm'))
          var imagefile = document.querySelector('#file')
          console.log(imagefile.files[0])
          data.append('file', imagefile.files[0])
          data.append('name', s.name)
          data.append('email', s.email)
          axios.post('http://192.168.1.222:8080/upload', data, {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
          })
            .then(response => {
              console.log(response)
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error.response)
            })
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```